# How much to charge for fictional substances in Victorian England?

Tags: economy, historical-settings, steampunk

I'm working on a little steampunk setting, which incorporates a lot of the elements of Victorian England. One of the similarities is the economy, in that prices and wages in this world are fairly historically accurate. One difference however, is the presence of several nonexistent materials, including Aerium and Prothane. Both of these are necessary to operate airships, with the Aerium lifting it off the ground and the Prothane (which resembles jet fuel) propelling it forward. How much do I charge for these substances?

Note: This setting is designed after the Ketty Jay series. If you've read it, that would be helpful.

---

A table of prices to give some perspective:

- Week's wage for an Unskilled Laborer: 3 shillings, 9 pence
- Dinner consisting of bread, cheese and beer: 3 pence
- Enough gin to get dead drunk on: 2 pence
- A shave: 6 pence
- A standard sword: 1 ducat, 3 shillings
- A silver pocketwatch: 11.5 ducats
- A horse: 25 ducats
- Renting a house (per year): 22 ducats

( A ducat is equal to nine shillings, a shilling is equal to twelve pence)

Comment: Have you thought about asking this on the worldbuilding stack exchange? I am not sure if we can help you here, even though I think this question is in topic (and interesting)

Comment: This isn't something we can answer here.  We don't do these types of suggestive brainstorming questions, because there is no objectively  "best" answer.  This is a purely subjective question; recommend you take this to world-building where the standards for subjectivity and brainstorming are less restrictive.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better venue for this kind of question.

Comment: I will move it there. Can I retract this question somehow?

Comment: No need! It's already on hold here, so there's no need to do anything special.

Answer (score -1):

### Real World Analogs

Let's look at some real world itms that I think are similar to your mytical ones, and figure out what they would cost

- Helium prices predicted to spike at $75.75 per thousand cubic feet.
- Propane costs $1.16 per gallon

According to http://mark.random-article.com/fudge/vmc.html :

- $75.75 id £0/17s/9.75d
- $1.16 is £0/0s/3.25d

### Imaginary Markets

Now imaginary markets are hard because we don't know in-world reasons they would go up and down or how that would be different from real world markets for these real world analogs.

I'd err on the side of making them more expensive if airships in this world are like ships in real Victorian England in terms of rarity.  If, however, every family has a air boat they sail to work every day, I'd price them closer to gasoline/petrol prices and do a similar conversion as the one above.

### Plot Devices

Imaginary markets might also change mid-game because of plot devices, or plot devices can be used to fix the price if you found you over or under valued a particular imaginary item. Sudden price increases could make a Aerium producer look for a new source, and the party might be sent out to finish this task.  Maybe there is too much competition in the market forcing down the price, and the party is hired to put competitors out of business.